# Is a 10GHz clock required to drive a 10Gb serial pin?

Tags: serial, ethernet, clock-speed

I am reading about the 10Gb/s Ethernet PHY for Altera FPGAs (datasheet [here](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/ug/xcvr_user_guide.pdf)). I was impressed to know that, at the hardware level, the 10Gb/s is done *serially*.

Naively, I would think to do 10Gb/s serially, one needs a 10GHz clock. However, 10GHz seems awefully high for a clock, and the datasheet does not specify a 10GHz clock anywhere.

How is 10Gb/s serial communication done? What clocks drive such transfers?

Comment: They now have 28Gbps working. Amazing 10GHz+ needs to be modulated with a suitable RLL code like 8B10B. I have not seen any specs but Gallium Arsenide over diamond substrate comes to mind at those frequencies with Laser over single and multi-mode fibre in single or quadrature modulation.

Comment: Note that you can have multi-bit symbols, so if instead of using binary levels you use 4-levels coding, you halve the required symbol frequency, at the expense of noise margin and circuit complexity. I'm not sure if it applies to Ethernet, though.

Comment: actually 10+Gbps will use 64B/66B where 8B10B is for 1Gbps and many under. Yes they use ◾Very high speed ADC: 5-bit, 4.25GS/s 3-bit ADC's, 17 GS/s

Comment: Dont know much about it, but some R&D in this area uses CMOS 40nm and 28nm for the SERDES clock and data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Altera parts you provide some reference base clock like 156.25Mhz.   Then the transceiver section has a PLL that brings the frequency up to I think half the rate.   So it'll be 5 Ghz for for the 10Gb/s link.  Or it might be lower if instead of having one 10Gb/s link you break it into 4 lanes like we do for the XAUI interface.   That clock and the parallel data get fed into the serializer and out comes 10Gb/s serial data.    That's the gist of it anyway.   You can read more about how the Altera transceivers work [here](http://www.altera.com/literature/wp/wp-01130-stxv-transceiver.pdf).

Here's an cut out from their documentation.

[image]